# In prestashop i added coiremitter plugin for payment so now i want from where order status updated?

Tags: php, prestashop

```
  public function updateOrderStatusInDetail($orderid)
  {
     date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
     $order = new Order($orderid);
     $db = Db::getInstance();
     $sql = "SELECT co.address, co.crp_amount, co.payment_status, co.date_added, cp.coin, cp.expire_on FROM coinremitter_order as co, coinremitter_payment as cp WHERE co.address = cp.address AND co.order_id = '$orderid' LIMIT 1";
     $results = $db->executes($sql);
     $data = $results[0];
     $address = $data['address'];
     $coin = $data['coin'];
     $status = $data['payment_status'];
     $expire_on = $data['expire_on'];

     error_log($status);
```

so here error_logs not worked so any other method for log?